# Add a custom method in a Model using CFWHEELS

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I am trying to add a custom method on one of my CFWheels Model but I am not able to do this. I have been reading the documentation but still not found an answer.

User.cfc

```
component extends="Component" {
    ...
    function getCustomSearch(){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to change:

```
model("users").findAll(...)
```

To

```
model("users").getCustomSearch(...)
```

In order to refactor some function.

Is this possible? In that case, what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your attention.

Regards.

Comment: Looks about right. What happens when you try it?

Comment: Wheels.MethodNotFound
The method getCustomSearch was not found in the user model.

Comment: @RodrigoR do you need to reload the app after making a change like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will need to be `model('user')`  not `users`; Wheels looks for the singular variant to match the models/User.cfc file.

Answer (score 0):

I have left my computer and when I came back it was working. Dan Roberts was right, it's necessary to reload.

Thanks to all for the help!